# Check for Zero being in a List Returns True Even if there is no Zero in the List

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am work with Spotlight (a library for recommender systems, based around PyTorch), and I am trying to build a set of sequences using the training data. One of the internal checks that Spotlight does when creating these sequences is to make sure that the item IDs are all non-zero, since zero is used as a padding value in the sequences.

I know that my input data has no zeros in it (it is being read from a file which I have made sure has no zeros), but for some reason the check within Spotlight says that there *is* a zero in the item ID list.

What is even more peculiar is what happens when I try this:

```
for id in interactions.item_ids:
    if id == 0:
        print("there is a zero ID")

# This is how Spotlight checks
if 0 in interactions.item_ids:
    print("there is a zero")
```

Only the *second* part prints any output. The first doesn't seem to detect any zeros.

This is very puzzling to me. To clarify, the item IDs are a NumPy array of `int64`s. The first ten entries look like this (I can provide a file with all 67000 or so of them, so you guys can check I'm not being stupid and that there is indeed no zero):

```
1339
1129
1953
1343
1061
1287
1405
31
3671
1293
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe provide an example of what `interactions.item_ids`looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've added the first ten to the post, and I can upload a file with all 67000 of them if need be.

Comment: Does your code print "False" everywhere if you do something like this? items_id = np.array([1339, 1129, 1953, 1343, 1061, 1287, 1405, 31, 3671, 1293], dtype=np.int64) print(items_id == 0)

Comment: I can't reproduce with a simple `numpy` array of `int64`s containing a `0`; if there is a `0` in it, both the loop and the `in` check identify it. Even works if there is a layer of wrapping (so it's `np.array([[1], [2], [0]], dtype=np.int64)`, not `np.array([1, 2, 0], dtype=np.int64)`).

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: At this point the file might not be a bad idea...

Comment: You supplied a text file, but your posted code assumes it magically turns into the desired data structure.  Instead, just hard-code the data structure that produces the problem.  We should not have to deal with file reading machinations.

Comment: If you work with numpy arrays, a check like " no_zeros = items_id[items_id == 0].size == 0 " should return no_zeros = True. There is probably something strange with your array structure. Plus, you should not use variable name "id" as it shadows a built-in name, but I do not think that it is the problem here...

Comment: It turns out that, as I was trying to sort out an MCVE, I fixed the problem! Explicitly doing `np.array(interactions.item_ids)` fixed the issue. Which is still odd, since calling `type(interactions.item_ids)` originally said that it was a numpy array anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, as I was trying to sort out an MCVE, I fixed the problem! Explicitly doing `np.array(interactions.item_ids)` fixed the issue.